# Swift CLLocationDistance error

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationdistance

I am building a learning app where i want to create pins and show the distance between current location and the pin but i get a really weird output

```
    func createPin(){
    var coord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.50, longitude: -0.13)

    var coord2 = CLLocation(latitude: coord.latitude, longitude: coord.longitude)

  var  kilometers:CLLocationDistance = coord2.distanceFromLocation(locNow)
    var str = NSString(format:  "%.2f", kilometers)


    let pin = Annotation(coordinate: coord, title: "LocationAlfa", subtitle: "distance : \(str)" + "  meters", dist: kilometers)

    map.addAnnotation(pin)

    println("\(kilometers)")
}
```

this is my create pin method and here i get my location distance

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!){

    let location = newLocation
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
    var region: () = centerMapOnLocation(location)

 //   self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    println("Latitude = \(newLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
    println("Longitude = \(newLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
    locNow = newLocation
}
```

and this is the shown distance in meters on the map : 5718215.17 (when the pin is made next to the pointed location on the map as the device location)

Comment: So is the problem that the output you got is much larger than your expected result?

Comment: exatcly....like 5000 km more than needed

Comment: you have to convert it to meter

Comment: the method distanceFromLocation already returns meters   func distanceFromLocation(location: CLLocation!) -> CLLocationDistance
Description Returns the distance (in meters) from the receiver’s location to the specified location.